# How can I tell if a game player is physically nearby?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, location

I have an iOS app in Swift that involves a small group of players found via Game Center, say 4 in all. One player is the leader, and they must know if each player is nearby or not nearby, say within 10 meters but this is flexible. Ideally, none of the four needs to have their app running in the foreground, and any player can be anywhere at any time, but I want to know pretty quick if someone is near.

So the question is, what is a good technique to determine if a player is nearby? I can think of a few possibilities like Location Manager regions, Bluetooth connections and so on, but it seems tricky. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I did some research about this for a similar app a few years back.

Using Location Manager to transmit and compare the players' coordinates on a server seems like the easiest option, but it has a serious number of drawbacks:

- Using the GPS and network features of an iOS device consume a lot of battery power. So it's very inefficient to constantly poll and transmit the user's location.
- For privacy reasons, Apple is very skeptical of apps that need to continually track the user's location even if the app is closed. You'd need to make a good case, or else you may get rejected.
- Again, for privacy reasons, transmitting the user's position is risky, so you would hope you have very good network security.
- The GPS features on certain iOS devices and circumstances can be inaccurate. Requiring a 10 meter radius might be too small.

For that reason, I'd recommend you explore whether the game idea you wish to implement is doable via [Apple's iBeacon technology](https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/). iBeacons are peer-to-peer, and a lot more accurate at close ranges, which sounds like it's what you're after. :)

Comment: After a little reading, I see an iPhone app can be an iBeacon transmitter itself, previously I thought the beacon had to be a standalone device. So the leader, whose app is running, can be a beacon that wakes up other nearby players and launches their app. This might work for me, thanks..

Comment: Yep! iOS devices themselves are able to be iBeacon hosts. The dedicated hardware is if you want to put a permanent hotspot down somewhere. Cool! Glad I could help! If that's all, could you please mark thanswer as accepted? :)